# Add a play count to database using ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When a user clicks .play it should add a play count if it doesn't have class alreadyplayed and then add class .alreadyplayed I am new to AJAX and cant seem to make it work.

```
$(".play").on('click', function () { 
if (!$(this).hasClass('alreadyplayed')) {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'addplay.php',
    data: songid = $(this).attr('sound_id'),
    }).done {
    $(this).addClass('alreadyplayed');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue is with `data: songid = $(this).attr('sound_id'),` & `done` function

You have to pass it as an object

```
data: { songid : $(this).attr('sound_id')} // Note curly braces
```

.done is a callback function

```
.done(function(response){
 //rest of code
}
```

You can try this snippet

```
 $(".play").on('click', function (event) { 
if (!$(this).hasClass('alreadyplayed')) {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'addplay.php',
    data: {songid = $(this).attr('sound_id')},
    }).done(function(response){ //End of ajax & start of done
        $(this).addClass('alreadyplayed');
       }) // end of done
    } // end of if loop
}); // end of click
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way, eventually when I figure it out I will make it post data v.s. ?songid= get method I will add that, just so someone knowing the addplay page couldn't make a play booster as easy, but for now it works good.

```
 $(".play").on('click', function () { 
    var soundid = $(this).attr('soundid');
    var thisplay = $(this);
        if (!$(this).hasClass('alreadyplayed')) {
                $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                data: $(this),
                url:'addplay.php?songid=' + soundid,        
                   });   
            }
            thisplay.addClass('alreadyplayed');
});
```